# Compilation Algorithm NetBeans Java

Tags: java, algorithm, windows-7, compilation, netbeans-7

It might sound stupid, but i decided to take the challenge to program the Translation Algorithm with help of OOP NetBeans - Java, having only basic knowledge of Java, and the theory only in the Translation Algorithm (Compiler).

I am here to ask for your assistance, if somehow any of you did something like Translation from one programming language into another I happy if you could provide me with the links to the information you've used or set me on to the right direction so I could start correctly!

Thank you in Advance

Best
Armani

Comment: Can you give any hint about what your algorithm should do? From what language to what language do you want to translate?

Comment: well, source code is based on Term Rewriting, it the Maude Language/System, moreover I am not trying to translate the whole language but the key parts of it (sort,var,op,eq,rl only, in case if you are familiar with this system) and the Target Code is the language that the Alloy Analyzer v4 uses. Generally, I've done the translation algorithm in theory, i mean on the paper only, i guess that should be initial point for me.

Answer (score 1):

Theory of compilation is a huge field of research, that among others include [formal languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language), [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), low level optimizations and more.

A good place to start learning about it is the **[Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811)** .

If you are using java, a useful tool that helps you do most of the [front-end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Front_end) tasks of a compiler is [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/)

Comment: Currently I am reading the same book, earlier edition, year 1986 :) !

Comment: and I assume that the JavaCC is similar to the ANTLR, isn't it?

Comment: @Armani: Yes it is. I have no experience with ANTLR, but they both suppose to have a similar functionality.